# MFC, File New with dialog to prompt for paramters and multiple Doc Types?

Tags: mfc

I have really tough question.

I have a program with six different kinds of MDI Windows.

There needs to be a dialog prompt to prompt the graphic dimensions (Height, Width) and then create six different kinds of MDI Window depending on what kind of graphics.

Question is:

I already got 6 MDI types working (to some extent).

What do I do to create a customized File|New to accommodate the need for a custom dialog screen?

For example, in MDI, there's a generic File|New dialog box. I wish to customize that in MFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you'll need to override the `CDocument` function that handles opening of new files; it's probably one of [`CDocument::OnNewDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewt90sw3%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`CDocument::OnOpenDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebc8c52a%28VS.80%29.aspx). I've also done this in the past by adding the following message map to `CMainFrame`, not sure which one the correct method is:

```
ON_COMMAND( ID_FILE_OPEN, &CMainFrame::OnFileOpen )
```

Then, to display a customized New File dialog, use the WINAPI [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. Note that you must use this function, MFC's `CFileDialog` will not work. Here's a code snippet from the `CMainFrame::OnFileOpen` function I listed above in the message map:

```
/**
 * Hook procedure for OPENFILENAME structure. This function processes messages from the custom 
 * controls added to the standard "Open File" dialog.
 *
 * @param [in]   hdlg 
 *  handle of the hdlg. 
 * @param [in]   uiMsg 
 *  message describing the user interface. 
 * @param [in]   wParam 
 *  the wParam field of the message. 
 * @param [in]   lParam 
 *  the lParam field of the message. 
 *
 * @return If the return value is zero, the default dialog box procedure processes the message; 
 *         otherwise it ignores the message.
 */
UINT_PTR CALLBACK OpenHexFileHook( HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  (void)(wParam);

  if( !::IsWindow( hdlg ) ) {
    return 0;
  }

  switch( uiMsg ) {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    /* Sent when an event occurs or the custom controls require information */
    {
      LPOFNOTIFY pOfnNotify = (LPOFNOTIFY)lParam;

      if( pOfnNotify == NULL ) {
        return 0;
      }
      CWinApp *app  = AfxGetApp();

      switch( pOfnNotify->hdr.code ) {
        case CDN_INITDONE:
        /* Sent when the system has finished arranging the controls in the dialog box */
        {
          CString rv;
          LRESULT idx;

          /* Configure the Hex file format ComboBox */
          HWND hHexFmt  = GetDlgItem( hdlg, IDC_HEX_FILE_FORMAT );

          ASSERT( hHexFmt );
          /* Clear existing content */
          ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0 );
          /* Add new items to the list */
          ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)_T("INTEL 32") );
          ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)_T("INTEL 16") );
          ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)_T("INTEL 8") );
          /* Read user's last selection from registry */
          rv  = app->GetProfileString( _T("Settings"), _T("HexFormat"), _T("INTEL 32") );
          idx = ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)((LPCTSTR)rv) );
          if( idx == CB_ERR ) {
            /* On error select the first item */
            idx = 0;
          }
          /* Set current selection to the previously selected item's index */
          ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_SETCURSEL, idx, 0 );

          /* Configure the Bytes per address ComboBox */
          HWND hBytePerLoc = GetDlgItem( hdlg, IDC_BYTES_PER_ADDR );

          ASSERT( hBytePerLoc );
          /* Clear existing content */
          ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0 );
          /* Add new items to the list */
          ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)_T("1") );
          ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)_T("2") );
          ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)_T("4") );
          /* Read user's last selection from registry */
          rv  = app->GetProfileString( _T("Settings"), _T("BytesPerAddr"), _T("1") );
          idx = ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)((LPCTSTR)rv) );
          if( idx == CB_ERR ) {
            /* On error select the first item */
            idx = 0;
          }
          /* Set current selection to the previously selected item's index */
          ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_SETCURSEL, idx, 0 );
          break;
        }

        case CDN_FILEOK:
        /* Sent when the user specifies a file name and clicks the OK button */
        {
          /* Save user selection for the Hex file format ComboBox */
          HWND hHexFmt  = GetDlgItem( hdlg, IDC_HEX_FILE_FORMAT );

          ASSERT( hHexFmt );
          /* Get current selection's index */
          LRESULT idx = ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0 );

          if( idx != CB_ERR ) {
            /* Get current selection's text length */
            LRESULT len1 = ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, idx, 0 );

            if( len1 != CB_ERR ) {
              TCHAR   *text = new TCHAR[len1 + 1];
              /* Get current selection's text */
              LRESULT len2  = ::SendMessage( hHexFmt, CB_GETLBTEXT, idx, (LPARAM)text );

              if( len1 == len2 ) {
                /* Write string to registry */
                app->WriteProfileString( _T("Settings"), _T("HexFormat"), text );
              }
              delete[] text;
            }
          }

          /* Save user selection for the Bytes per address ComboBox */
          HWND hBytePerLoc  = GetDlgItem( hdlg, IDC_BYTES_PER_ADDR );

          ASSERT( hBytePerLoc );
          /* Get current selection's index */
          idx = ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0 );

          if( idx != CB_ERR ) {
            /* Get current selection's text length */
            LRESULT len1 = ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, idx, 0 );

            if( len1 != CB_ERR ) {
              TCHAR   *text = new TCHAR[len1 + 1];
              /* Get current selection's text */
              LRESULT len2  = ::SendMessage( hBytePerLoc, CB_GETLBTEXT, idx, (LPARAM)text );

              if( len1 == len2 ) {
                /* Write string to registry */
                app->WriteProfileString( _T("Settings"), _T("BytesPerAddr"), text );
              }
              delete[] text;
            }
          }
          break;
        }

        default:
          /* Do nothing */
          break;
      }
      break;
    }

    default:
      /* Do nothing */
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}


void CMainFrame::OnFileOpen()
{
  std::basic_string<TCHAR> filterSpec;

  /* Use *.hex filter */
  filterSpec  = _T("Hex Files (*.hex)");
  filterSpec += (std::basic_string<TCHAR>::value_type)'\0';
  filterSpec += _T("*.hex");
  filterSpec += (std::basic_string<TCHAR>::value_type)'\0';


  OPENFILENAME ofn                  = { sizeof(ofn) };
  TCHAR        filePath[MAX_PATH]   = { 0 };
  TCHAR        fileTitle[MAX_PATH]  = { 0 };

  ofn.hwndOwner           = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd();
  ofn.hInstance           = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
  ofn.lpstrFilter         = filterSpec.c_str();
  ofn.lpstrCustomFilter   = NULL;
  ofn.nMaxCustFilter      = 0;
  ofn.nFilterIndex        = 1;
  ofn.lpstrFile           = filePath;
  ofn.nMaxFile            = sizeof(filePath) / sizeof(TCHAR);
  ofn.lpstrFileTitle      = fileTitle;
  ofn.nMaxFileTitle       = sizeof(fileTitle) / sizeof(TCHAR);
  ofn.lpstrInitialDir     = NULL;
  ofn.lpstrTitle          = _T("Select Intel HEX file");
  ofn.Flags               = OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | 
                            OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | 
                            OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
  ofn.lpstrDefExt         = _T("hex");
  ofn.lCustData           = NULL;
  ofn.lpfnHook            = OpenHexFileHook;
  ofn.lpTemplateName      = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_HEX_FILE_OPEN);
  ofn.FlagsEx             = 0;

  if( GetOpenFileName( &ofn ) != false ) {
    AfxGetApp()->m_pDocManager->OpenDocumentFile( ofn.lpstrFile );

    SetTitle( ofn.lpstrFileTitle );
  }
}
```

In that project I added 2 ComboBoxes to the standard File Open dialog. [These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646960%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Custom_Templates) MSDN docs describe how to customize the standard dialogs. This is the resource file (.rc2) customization that I used:

```
//
// HexViewer.RC2 - resources Microsoft Visual C++ does not edit directly
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#error this file is not editable by Microsoft Visual C++
#endif //APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Add manually edited resources here...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// File Open Dialog Template
//

IDD_HEX_FILE_OPEN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 370, 40
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CONTROL | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
EXSTYLE WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "&HEX file format:", IDC_HEX_FILE_FORMAT_TEXT, 67, 2, 58, 8, SS_NOTIFY
    COMBOBOX        IDC_HEX_FILE_FORMAT, 130, 0, 164, 100,
                    CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "&Bytes per address:", IDC_BYTES_PER_ADDR_TEXT, 67, 20, 63, 8, SS_NOTIFY
    COMBOBOX        IDC_BYTES_PER_ADDR, 130, 18, 164, 100,
                    CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Note that this method of customization is recommended only if you're programming for Windows XP and older versions. From Vista onwards MS recommends using the [Common Item Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913%28VS.85%29.aspx) API for customizing, but I've never used that.